# Not receiving mail via sendgrid using nodejs though the app runs with 0 error

Tags: node.js, email, visual-studio-code, sendgrid, nodemailer

I am just a beginner in nodejs working on a email functionality for an open source project.
Further I Made this test project on my local machine to learn to work with sendgrid with nodejs but got stuck badly.
It is not even showing any error!!
Help me please.
This is how the test project directory looks.
[Test directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h4kD.png)

This is my app.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {
    to: 'anushkasharma112000@gmail.com',
    from: 'xxxx@gmail.com', // My Verified email at https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth
    subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
//ES6
sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => { }, error => {
        console.error(error);

        if (error.response) {
            console.error(error.response.body)
        }
    });
```

I have a .env file that has only 1 line

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY='SG.somelettersanddigits.somelettersanddigits'
```

And a package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: I've not used sendgrid before, and just now created an account, verified the new sender, got a key and used the same template code.. and it worked at first try. As I see, for your side all is ok.. don't know the reason. 1. try to use SENDGRID_API_KEY="yourkeyyourkeyyourkey" instead of SENDGRID_API_KEY='yourkeyyourkeyyourkey' 2. console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY) and make sure that you got that in your file. 3. May the issue from they side, cuz on registration part I couldn't verify my account for 2FA, and got error on accout verification 2-3 times

Comment: Yes, the problem was on their side. I raised a ticket and they helped me with it :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you're fixed that

Comment: @AvaniSingh can I know how you solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code and just added in my emails and it worked fine. I would suggest deleting your api key and creating a new one. Also like boolfalse said: console.log(`your api key ${process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY}`) to make sure it's coming through okay.